# ADExplorer, how to search with "distinguishedName contains" condition?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I'm using ADExplorer 1.42 from Microsoft. I'm not very versed at this program so please kindly help me out with a search-related problem.

Right click on a node(e.g., CN=NlscanStaff) and select *Search Container...* , with default search attributes, I can see all objects inside NlscanStaff listed as result.

[image]

Note that there is a CN=CHJTEST object listed.

**Now, my question is, how to search for CHJTEST specifically?**

I tried search condition:

- Attribute : distinguishedName
- Relation : contains
- Value : CN=CHJTEST

Click Add , then Search . **But no result**.

[image]

Can someone tell me what's going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Wouldn't the value just be CHJTEST?

Comment: Tried that, same result.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You will want to use the Attribute "cn" and not "distinguishedName" for that type of wildcard search in the ADExplorer utility from Sysinternals.  Do not include CN= in the Value field, just the portion of the name you want to search for. E.g. CHJTEST)

If you have problems using the "cn" attribute for this simple search, I would recommend upgrading to version 1.44 of ADExplorer.

Comment: Great, thanks, now I got it. I was misled by the search result GUI.

Comment: 0down vote
 


I have 1.44 and tried to search for some information in the attribute managedBy, what ever I try it doesn't work to find specific values. Only "managedBy not empty" works. Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 2):

Solution found according to MagusNet.

Add a live screen shot:

[image]